# x*x mod(p) most efficient pythonic way?

Tags: python, modulo

What is the most efficient way of doing x = x*x mod(p) in python:
(I know that x < p)

```
x = pow(a, 2, p)
```

or

```
x = x*x % p
```

or

```
x *= x
x %= p
```

(I think that x*x is the same as x**2 if measured by eficiency, if no than fix me).

Comment: The second or the third. The first has an arbitrary exponent and thus will have some *control structures* around it. But the difference between the second and third will be very small.

Comment: I suppose *a* should be *x*. And why do you ask this when you can easily do a test yourself and measure the time it takes to repeat each operation 1000000 times.

Comment: Python includes a [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) function. Test it.

Comment: IPython's `%timeit` suggests that `x*x%p` is about 50% faster than `pow`, at least for relatively small numbers. 280 ns vs 180 ns. For larger numbers (tens of digits) the difference gets a bit larger, about a factor of four.

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: @Aaron: who says this is about optimization. You can analyze this from a theoretical perspective (for instance look at the intermediate code, etc.).

Comment: I'd use `x**2 % p` because it's probably the most readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a `timeit` module for testing exactly this sort of thing:

```
$ python -m timeit 'x = 2000; p = 2002; x = pow(x, 2, p)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.115 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'x = 2000; p = 2002; x = (x * x) % p' 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0542 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'x = 2000; p = 2002; x *= x; x %= p' 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0614 usec per loop
```

Your answer is that `(x * x) % p` and `x *= x; x %= p` are about the same, but `pow` is much slower.

Comment: That's the whole thing! The quoted bit here is copy-pasted from a terminal session. The bits in quotes are evaluated 10M times by the `timeit` module, which is part of the standard library.